# Validate Django form GET request

Tags: django, forms, validation

I'm trying to validate the data passed to a Django form via GET request. Typical form usage is validating `request.POST`, but I would like to validate data for a search form, which is a `GET` request. I have the following code, which uses `FormMixin` with `ListView`, which works OK, but I return a full or empty queryset, neither of which will trip the form validation.

```
class PostSearchView(FormMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'blog/post_search.html'
    paginate_by = getattr(settings, 'PAGINATE_BY', 10)
    form_class = SearchForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('post_search')

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'q' in self.request.GET:
            form_class = self.get_form_class()
            form = form_class(self.request.GET)
            if form.is_valid():
                q = form.cleaned_data['q']
                post_list = Post.objects.is_published().filter(Q(title__icontains=q) | Q(body__icontains=q))
            else:
                post_list = Post.objects.none()
        else:
            form = self.get_form()
            post_list = Post.objects.none()
        self.object_list = post_list
        context = self.get_context_data(post_list=post_list, form=form)
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

A query that is an empty string (just hitting "search") should return the same view with a validation error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just build the error view in the second 'else' clause? If "q" is not in the get parameters then there is no query

Comment: Yea, paste your query url here.

Answer (score 0):

The code I had was correct. I think maybe it was a caching issue. Sorry to waste everyone's time.

However, some improvements that should have been made:

- `success_url` is unnecessary because there shouldn't be anything to redirect to; it just re-renders the same view with additional query parameters
- Passing `post_list` to the context is redundant and slightly harmful; by storing it in `self.object_list`, `post_list` and `object_list` are recognized as the view's queryset and are automatically paginated and added to the context. By putting `post_list` back into the context, paginated is blown away.
- To ensure pagination works in query strings and just for general usability, the query (either `form.cleaned_data['q']` or forced to be `None`) should be explicitly passed to the context.
- It might be worth renaming `form` to `post_search_form` or just something else if the search form is going to be on several pages via context processor.

The improved view:

```
class PostSearchView(FormMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'blog/post_search.html'
    paginate_by = getattr(settings, 'PAGINATE_BY', 10)
    form_class = SearchForm

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'q' in self.request.GET:
            form_class = self.get_form_class()
            form = form_class(self.request.GET)
            if form.is_valid():
                q = form.cleaned_data['q']
                post_list = Post.objects.is_published().filter(Q(title__icontains=q) | Q(body__icontains=q))
            else:
                q = None
                post_list = Post.objects.none()
        else:
            q = None
            form = self.get_form()
            post_list = Post.objects.none()
        self.object_list = post_list
        context = self.get_context_data(form=form, query=q)
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

The pagination template include:

```
{% if page_obj.has_other_pages %}
<nav>
    <ul class="pager">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
        <li class="previous"><a href="?{% if query %}q={{ query }}&amp;{% endif %}page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">&larr; Newer</a></li>
        {% endif %}
        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
        <li class="next"><a href="?{% if query %}q={{ query }}&amp;{% endif %}page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Older &rarr;</a></li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
</nav>
{% endif %}
```